# Weird behavior of defined?(super) check

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Lately I came across some weird behavior with the `defined?` operator used to check if `super` keyword can be used in current context. Usually it works fine, but when I tried to combine the `defined? super` check with a tiny bit of metaprogramming, it gave me unexpected results.

It's easier to show then to describe, so here is a distilled example to illustrate the problem:

```
class A; 
  def self.def_f!; 
    singleton_class.send(:define_method, :f) { defined? super }
  end
end
class AA < A; end
```

(`A` and `AA` classes both have `.def_f!` class method)

```
A.def_f!

A.f  # => nil
AA.f # => nil
```

(`A.f` has no super and `AA.f` dispatches to `A.f`, so everything's OK so far, but...)

```
AA.def_f! # define its own .f method in the AA class

AA.f # => "super"
A.f  # => "super" # WHY???
```

Could anyone explain me the last line? `A.f` has no super method, then why it returns `"super"` instead of `nil`? Is it a bug?

(I tried it in 1.9.2 and 1.9.3—same results)

**UPD:** I opened a ticket on the Ruby bugtracker: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6644

Comment: After looking at the Ruby sources, I think you found a real bug here. You should report it to the Ruby bugtracker.

Comment: And if you do, don't forget to post a link to the issue here! `:)`

Comment: @NiklasB. Done: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6644

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so @Niklas was right, I reported this issue to the Ruby bugtracker and they confirmed and  fixed the bug: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6644.

As far as I've understood, the fix will be included in ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there are a few quirks with `define_method`, this is not a problem with `defined?(super)` really, but more with `define_method`. Having said that, whenever I encounter an edge case like this with `define_method`, I usually just end up eval'ing a string of Ruby code and it always ends up working as expected.

```
module M;
  def def_f!
    singleton_class.class_eval <<-RUBY
      def f
        defined?(super)
      end
    RUBY
  end
end

class A; extend M; end
class AA < A; end

A.def_f!

p A.f  # => nil
p AA.f # => nil

AA.def_f! # define its own .f method in the AA class

p AA.f # => "super"
p A.f # => nil
```

As to why it works this way, I'm not experienced enough with Ruby's source to know, maybe somebody who knows more than I do can chime in. But for practical purposes, evaluating a string has always worked for me.

Comment: I still believe that the problem is more with `defined?(super)`, but thanks for the workaround.